# Is charge batteries in series faster than in parallel?

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, series, time

I would like to know if charging 7 lithium-ion batteries in series with BMS 7S are faster than simply charge them in parallel. Please for your advice, thank you!

Comment: It depends on your charger. A high voltage, low current output charger will charge a bunch of series batteries faster because it can make full use of its output power. A low voltage, high current output charger will charge a bunch of parallel batteries faster for the same reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be very careful with powerful chargers to charge your li ion.
One cell can handle 1A load current the other 20A
Don't mix load current with the famous C, if a cell is 3000mah @ 1C your max charge is 3A.
If it is 0.5C it would be max 1.5A charge

Look up the cell specs and adjust your charger to there max.
If a cell is rated with 5A charge or rated with 30A charge.
If you have 10 cells parallel, the max charge would be 4.0 V at 50A or 300A, that depends on your cell structure
If you have 10 cells in series(all the same type btw), your max charging would be 20.0 V at 5A or 20.0 V at 50A.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a 10 watt charger, and batteries with 10Wh capacity, they will take an hour to charge, whatever the configuration.

Now if you have a 7S battery, you'd better be using a 7S charger. If a 7P battery, then a charger that can handle 1S will be required.

It may be easier/cheaper to find a high powered charger for a many S rather than 1S configuration, as often a charger will also be rated with a maximum output current regardless of the cell voltage, so a higher output voltage will deliver a higher power.

Comment: So they will charge 7 times faster than parallel?